# Oracle database does not build properly on docker

Tags: oracle, docker

I want to run oracle database in docker, but it doesn't work. The os I'm using is mac, and I cloned and brought the Oracle database image from github.

I have completed the build of Docker and confirmed that it works normally in the container.

[image]

And I used the command to run sqlplus, and entered the id and password normally in the input fields, but it is not being executed.

chat GPT told me to wait, "From the Docker log output, I can confirm that Oracle database XE is configuring." But I waited for more than 30 minutes, and I ran it again before going to bed at night and went to sleep, but it did not complete.
[image]
log

```
 docker logs -f oracle_db
ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS AND SYSTEM: 1234
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration succeeded.
Configuring Oracle Database XE.
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be may different reasons for the database not to start up, but the most likely one is probably a lack of resources:

- try to increase the memory resources in Docker in the [settings](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/) to 6GB
- try to start the container with 4GB and 2CPU's (`--memory="4g"`)

If this all does not help, try a different image or build one from [scratch](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase).